# Sasuke's clan dream

Tags: naruto

In volume 1 chapter 3: Hatake Kakashi, Kakashi asks Naruto, Sasuke, and Sakura what they like, dislike, what their dreams for the future are, and stuff like that. First it was Naruto, he talked about how he likes ramen, dislikes waiting for ramen to cook, and how he dreams to surpass all the previous Hokages, and even become one himself. Then there was Sasuke. He said he had a dream, or to better put it, an ambition. The resurrection of his clan. And to kill a "certain man",

> which was Itachi, his older brother. But eventually he did kill him, and than he changed his goal... again.

My question is if restoring his clan is still his dream, or has he just forgotten all about it.

He only has one daughter with Sakura, and it seems that he is not planning on having anymore children since he is mostly out of the village on missions. So, did he forget about that dream or just realized that restoring a whole clan was almost impossible? Or did he just say that because he wanted revenge?

Comment: I think restoring his clan is still ongoing, or at least he's still have a daughter that have a Sharingan. So his grandchild also should have a Sharingan.

Comment: i think, for restoring his clan only, he has gone out of the village. ;) if u know what i mean.

Answer (score 1):

I say Sasuke's dream was his wish as a child. He wanted to have the atmosphere of his family and his clan around him again, but, like most of us, as he grew up he was struck by the reality and had adjust to certain situations. He also realized his wish is not possible, or at least he can find that happiness when he achieved his other goals.

At the end, he even wanted to become Hokage which means protecting the peace in the village has become his number one priority. Given the history of the powerful Uchiha clan, the misfortunes that they had regarding their eyes, and the misfortunes they brought to the village (Madara & Obito), I think Sasuke decided not to follow that dream. Even if his family ended up with Sharingan, they will be shinobi of Konoha, the title that Itachi was so proud of having.